# I'm trying to read data from my SQL Server Compact database, but I keep getting the same error

Tags: c#, sql

I'm querying a [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) database with "SELECT * FROM User", and I get an error parsing the query:

> Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 15,Token in error = User

How do I fix this?

The code I'm using is this:

```
public static List<User> GetUsers()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnection))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, con))
        {
            SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string user = reader.GetString(1);
                User usr = null;
                using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
                    s.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user.ToCharArray()), 0, user.Length);
                    s.Position = 0;
                    usr = (User)serializer.Deserialize(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```

Note: I also get this error trying to add information.

Comment: Can you show the sql you are executing?

Comment: ive added additional information

Comment: On which line does the error occur? new Command, or ExecuteReader?

Comment: it occurs on 
SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: So basically it is trying to do a standard select from a table called *User* . Are you sure you are connecting to the correct DB?

Comment: im sorry i must have mistyped my question, i am pulling my data from a table called User, correct. not as stated earlier, ill fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the token 'User' is not being understood. Just a guess (I don't have a SqlCE to test on) try "quoting" the table name with square brackets:

```
"SELECT * FROM [User]"
```